# Android Gradle: Cannot find symbol Q

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Gradle build fails in Android studio. I have been unsuccessful in trying to resolve this issue.

/android/capacitor/src/main/java/com/getcapacitor/plugin/Share.java:54: error: cannot find symbol

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {`
^

symbol:   variable Q
location: class VERSION_CODES

Comment: Mind posting a fuller stack-trace for your error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're not using the correct buildTools. Try upgrading your build tools to at least Android 10.0 (Q) in the SDK Manager.

Assuming you're using Android Studio, click here

[image]

around the top of your screen, and then download at least Android 10.0 (Q) to get what you're looking for.

I do recommend, however, that you upgrade to the latests Android 11.0 (R) if you can instead to get all of the latests features!

Comment: I reinstalled my android studio, installed Android 11.0 as suggested, readded the android platform to my project and it's now okay.

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your problem, I'd love it if you could mark it as helpful and all!

Answer (score 0):

On build.gradle change your sdk and your target to 29 and sync again

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29 //<-- HERE
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "yourAppName"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29 //<-- HERE
        versionCode 00001
        versionName "0.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```